# Limit of a List

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-value

Is it possible to take the limit of a list instead of using the Limit method? I'll try to explain what I mean.

I am generating a list of numbers that converge to some number. The generated numbers are the results of a function that gets reran with higher numerical precision, and so the numbers in the list should become closer to the algebraic limit with each addition. Is there some way for Mathematica to understand this?

I tried to use the Limit function initially, but it generated a bunch of errors. Alternatively, if someone sees an issue with how I try to use Limit, advice there will also be appreciated.

For context, here is my code:

```
AmpLinePlot[v_, delta_, Amin_, Amax_, depth_] := 
  Module[{PoincarePoint, PoincareMap, BoxCount, measureData, line, j, 
  scaleList, A, pointsList, dimensionList},
  A = Amin; pointsList = {}; dimensionList = {};
  scaleList = {1/10, 1/20, 1/30, 1/40, 1/50};

  PoincarePoint[{{y_, z_}, \[Gamma]_}] := 
    Flatten[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. 
    NDSolve[{a'[t] == b[t], 
      b'[t] == -v b[t] - (a[t]) ((a[t])^2 - 1) ((a[t])^2 - 4) + \[Gamma]   Sin[t], a[0] == y, b[0] == z}, {a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}] /. t -> 2 Pi]];

  PoincareMap[{y_, z_}, \[Gamma]_, nMin_, nMax_] := Module[{M, n},
    M[0] := {y, z};
    M[n_] := M[n] = PoincarePoint[{M[n - 1], \[Gamma]}];
    Table[M[n], {n, nMin, nMax}]];

    BoxCount[points_, scale_] := 
      Module[{xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, xPoints, yPoints},
      xPoints = Transpose[points][[1]];
      yPoints = Transpose[points][[2]];
      xMin = Min[xPoints];
      xMax = Max[xPoints];
      yMin = Min[yPoints];
      yMax = Max[yPoints];
      Count[Flatten[BinCounts[points, {xMin - 1, xMax + 1, scale}, {yMin - 1, yMax + 1, scale}]], _?(# > 0 &)]];

   While[A <= Amax,
     AppendTo[pointsList, PoincareMap[{0, 0}, A, 100, depth]];
     A = A + delta];

    For[j = 1, j <= Length[pointsList], j++,
      measureData = Map[{Log[1/#], Log[BoxCount[pointsList[[j]], #]]} &, scaleList];
      line = LinearModelFit[measureData, x, x];
      AppendTo[dimensionList, 
      If[(line["BestFit"] /. x -> 1) == 0, 0, line["BestFit"][[2]]/x]]];

   dimensionList];
```

The function returns a list of numbers. The numbers represent box dimensions of the chaotic DE defined in the function, if anyone is curious. If the function is called with Amin = Amax, then it will output a list with only one number. I tried using Limit for this scenario like this:

```
Limit[AmpLinePlot[.07, .1, 3, 3, n], n -> 5000, Direction -> 1, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
```

and consequently errors that seem to come from my function, not Limit. I'm guessing that Limit called the function using an invalid n, somehow.

I am hoping that Mathematica can determine the algebraic limit somehow because my current method of numerically finding the dimension is generating some artifacts.

Comment: Your function `AmpLinePlot[.07, .1, 3, 3, n]` doesn't run for `n=1,10,100,1000` etc.

Comment: Somewhat correct. It doesn't run for n < 100, but it should run for anything higher. The reason behind this is the line "AppendTo[pointsList, PoincareMap[{0, 0}, A, 100, depth]];". The "100" effectively ignores the first 100 points. This is only to make cleaner pictures of long-term behavior; I could easily change it to 0. Do you think that could be a part of the problem with Limit?

Comment: You can't find a limit for a general numerical function. But if you have a sequence of numbers, you could try your luck with a `FindSequenceFunction` function and hopefully it would find a symbolic formula for your sequence.

Comment: So you are generating a finite trajectory through state space (Poincare map) and capturing the minimal box that contains it, correct? What assurances do you have that the limit exists, and more importantly is reachable in a finite series of points generated? Interesting problem...

Comment: Yes for the Poincare Map, no for the minimal box. I'm calculating the box dimension which is, ideally, many infinitely small boxes. Also, the box dimension always exists algebraically for chaotic attractors. With a finite amount of points, though, I don't know how attainable the limit is. I was hoping Limit would solve that for me, but that might be too optimistic. I may have to stick with my current method and sort out the artifact kinks. It is very interesting! My professor has been working in this area for awhile, and he's letting me help.